# Writing less than or equal in label of graduated classes in symbology of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, arcgis-10.3

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3.

How do I write less than or equal in the break values of the labeling in symbology?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit the label text manually.

Just copy and paste this symbol: **≤**

Similarly, use this symbol for greater than or equal to: **≥**