# Greater than or equal to in graduated colors label using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro

The default symbol when using the Graduated Colors symbology in ArcGIS Pro seems to be “less than or equal to” (≤). I was wondering if there was a way to change it to “greater than or equal to” (≥)? Someone had a similar question for ArcMap at [Writing less than or equal in label of graduated classes in symbology of ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169242). And the solution to their question was to past ≥ into the label. I tried doing this in Pro, but it would not accept it.

Does anyone know if it is possible to change the symbology labels from ≤ to ≥ in ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, class breaks in the ArcGIS Pro GUI and ArcPy are built around upper bounds, which makes working with lower-bound breaks a hassle.  One can use [Modify a CIM definition - Python CIM access - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/python-cim-access.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_9DD477B28F684819A1D7CAE312BEFD49), but that gets into the weeds quickly and tends to be a bridge too far for a typical ArcGIS Pro GUI user.

One approach I have used with ArcGIS Pro GUI users that involves some [Write Arcade expressions for symbology and labeling - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/production/aviation/write-arcade-expressions-for-symbology-and-labeling.htm) but still seems manageable is to use Arcade to create custom lower-bound breaks implemented as unique symbology.  All the user has to do is specify the field and break points as an expression:

```js
// user-provided information
var field = $feature.field;     // set field to classify
var breaks = [                  // lower-bound break points
  1,
  2,
  ...
];

// generate custom lower-bound breaks
var breaks = Reverse(Sort(breaks));
for(var index in breaks) {
  if(field >= breaks[index]){
    return ">= " + Text(breaks[index]);
  }
}
return null;
```

Although this code properly classifies and labels, the initial sorting of the symbology labels is text-based, so sometimes the user has to manually move the classes around to get a proper ascending or descending label order.

Answer (score -1):

Alt + 242 works for changing the symbology, but doesn't seem to work if you want to change the symbol in a legend.